# Trying to compare two words in alphabetical order using a while loop to see which one if guess comes before of after word

Tags: java, performance, methods, compareto

I am trying to compare two words and see if guess comes before word using `compareTo()`

```
while(!guess.equals(word)){
    if(compare < 0){
        System.out.println(word + " Comes before your guess. ");
        detail(); 
    } else if(compare > 0) {
        System.out.println(word + "Comes after your guess. "); 
        detail(); 
    }
}
System.out.println("You guessed it!");
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. You forgot to ask a question. Please [edit] your post to add it.

Comment: Thank you, I have included a piece of code as well

Comment: Where are you using `compareTo` and what is your question?

Comment: I had initialized it in the variable compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s1.compareTo(s2)` is

- positive(>0) if `s1` comes after `s2`,
- negative(<0) if `s1` comes before `s2`,
- zero (0) if `s1` and `s2` coincide

So, in your case you should

```
    if(word.compareTo(guess) < 0){
        System.out.println(word + " Comes before your guess. ");
        detail(); 
    } else if(word.compareTo(guess) > 0) {
        System.out.println(word + "Comes after your guess. "); 
        detail(); 
    }
```